# Can I overcome colliding base @Path in Jax-RS?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a base collection of REST resources annotated to correspond to certain paths. 
Psuedo code:

```
@Path("/collection")
class Stuff {

  @Path("/{id}")
  @GET
  public String get(@PathParm("id") int id) {
    return String.format("Item #%d". id);
  }
}
```

Now, I need to add a sub resource to this collection without changing the class `Stuff`, but adding code like below doesn't work:

```
@Path("/collection/{id}")
class StuffPlugin {

  @Path("/extra")
  @GET
  public String extra(@PathParm("id") int id) {
    return String.format("Extra info about item #%s", id);
  }
}
```

This used to work in RESTeasy 2.3 but now, upgrading to version 3.0.4 the latter seems to shadow the `Stuff` class when RESTeasy is looking for possible path matches and thus break the whole structure of my app.
How would this be accomplished in RESTeasy 3?

Thank you

---

#### PS

I am adding the provider classes programmatically like below and everything that doesn't have colliding base paths is working fine.

```
public class EntryPoint extends Application {
  public EntryPoint() {}

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    return new HashSet<Class<?>>() {
      {
         add(Stuff.class);
         add(StuffPlugin.class);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RestEasy 3.x is based on JAX-RS 2.0 which is a new specification update in JAX-RS.

The developer who maintains the RestEasy has already written a blog post about weird path matching algorithm !

http://bill.burkecentral.com/2013/05/29/the-poor-jax-rs-request-dispatching-algorithm/

In your case it might have worked earlier as RestEasy was implementing the old spec which was not so strict about the implementation of the matching algorithm, which may not work now..

Better be you reflector the code and define the resources appropriately !

Comment: Wow, I agree with the author that the JAX-RS 2 spec is poor. It makes this use case very convoluted.

Comment: But he pointed me to the migration guide at http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html/Migration_from_older_versions.html where he mentions a switch that may help me out: "There is one config switch I added so that Resteasy will ignore the Spec defined class expression filtering step and instead match base on the full expressions of each JAX-RS method."